# encfs on OSX Mavericks: illegal hardware instruction

Tags: macos, crash, filesystems, homebrew, fuse

I use `encfs` to encode the personal documents that I keep on cloud drives. I have written a script that mounts the encoded folders at startup on MacOS, and it works flawlessly on two of my Macs. The third Mac (iMac 2008), though, fails to run `encfs` command, crashes with the error "illegal hardware instruction" that I have never encountered before. I wonder what is preventing `encfs` from running correctly.

I have installed "OSXFuse" using "Homebrew" along with some other fuse-based file systems such as `sshfs` and `bindfs` that I use regularly on the same iMac with no issue. I have the same version of Mavericks installed on all my computers (10.9.5).

Here is my `brew config`:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: a0d9ecf1ce73acee32de0eca937d25dfa80b0cd5
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.9.5-x86_64
Xcode: 6.0.1
CLT: 6.0.0.0.1.1410400753
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /Users/mah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
```

Here is the crash log from the last crash:

```
Process:         encfs [869]
Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/encfs/1.7.5_1/bin/encfs
Identifier:      encfs
Version:         0
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  zsh [625]
Responsible:     iTerm [616]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-29 15:41:15.243 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  74ECAA66-AC67-A002-50AB-F34FFEFA7DC2


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
/usr/local/lib/librlog.5.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   librlog.5.dylib                 0x000000010df749b7 _GLOBAL__I_a + 7
1   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5f0c2e ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 268
2   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5f0dba ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
3   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5eda62 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 308
4   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5ed9eb ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 189
5   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5ed9eb ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 189
6   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5ed8f6 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 54
7   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5e11da dyld::initializeMainExecutable() + 189
8   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5e4560 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2419
9   dyld                            0x00007fff6a5e027b dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 477
10  dyld                            0x00007fff6a5e005e _dyld_start + 54

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x000000010df749b0  rcx: 0x00007fff51d288c0  rdx: 0x00007fff51d28760
  rdi: 0x0000000000000001  rsi: 0x00007fff51d28750  rbp: 0x00007fff51d276a0  rsp: 0x00007fff51d27690
   r8: 0x00007fff6a613178   r9: 0x00007fff51d27600  r10: 0x00007fff964500e1  r11: 0x00007fff9598e6c6
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x00007fff6a6130b0  r14: 0x00007fff6a61b4c0  r15: 0x000000010df7a378
  rip: 0x000000010df749b7  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000010df749b0

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6


Binary Images:
       0x10ded7000 -        0x10dee9fff +encfs (0) <0CDF19BF-6E75-3CC4-BBCA-E8552FC2BE0F> /usr/local/bin/encfs
       0x10defd000 -        0x10df33fff +libencfs.6.dylib (0) <30EA3D2B-3481-3CB5-9808-77A4E0C372EF> /usr/local/Cellar/encfs/1.7.5_1/lib/libencfs.6.dylib
       0x10df72000 -        0x10df79ff7 +librlog.5.dylib (0) <B4C44B6B-BF72-3B1B-97F2-9BBC7EA64AA7> /usr/local/lib/librlog.5.dylib
       0x10df89000 -        0x10dfc2ff7 +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <C70E951B-86CD-3F4C-A1DC-6AB02B838B0F> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10dfde000 -        0x10e0effef +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <B3590A5D-883A-337D-84F8-8217F641E340> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10e165000 -        0x10e189ff7 +libboost_serialization-mt.dylib (0) <EC54345E-8170-3663-82E7-0308E1BCCDCB> /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib
       0x10e201000 -        0x10e20eff7 +libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib (0) <8A57889F-24FE-3923-87B1-9BE986A3A07E> /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
       0x10e221000 -        0x10e223ff3 +libboost_system-mt.dylib (0) <28E41007-7056-3375-A009-BB8E0FC78AF1> /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
       0x10e22a000 -        0x10e233fff +libintl.8.dylib (0) <4E31E35C-6964-39DE-86EC-7CD308FBC206> /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
       0x10e23d000 -        0x10e257fff +libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib (0) <C638BF8A-4AF0-3F4E-9AF7-09CC5130F911> /usr/local/lib/libosxfuse_i64.2.dylib
    0x7fff6a5df000 -     0x7fff6a612817  dyld (239.4) <7AD43B9B-5CEA-3C7E-9836-A06909F9CA56> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff884db000 -     0x7fff884f5fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.92.1) <C4E4A18D-3C3B-3C9C-8709-A4270D998DE7> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff88939000 -     0x7fff8895dfff  libxpc.dylib (300.90.2) <AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8899e000 -     0x7fff8899eff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff88e26000 -     0x7fff88e27ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff894b7000 -     0x7fff894bdff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.90.1) <3C3D3DA8-32B9-3243-98EC-D89B9A1670B3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8995d000 -     0x7fff8995eff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff89e49000 -     0x7fff89e8bff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff89e8c000 -     0x7fff89eb5ff7  libc++abi.dylib (49.1) <21A807D3-6732-3455-B77F-743E9F916DF0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8bfb4000 -     0x7fff8bfb7ff7  libdyld.dylib (239.4) <7C9EC3B7-DDE3-33FF-953F-4067C743951D> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8cd6f000 -     0x7fff8cd71ff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.15) <4998CB6A-9D54-390A-9F57-5D1AC53C135C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8cdd8000 -     0x7fff8cf90ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (511.35) <6F097DA7-147C-32A1-93D2-728A64CF0DC2> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8d0c7000 -     0x7fff8d0c8fff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff8d1bc000 -     0x7fff8d1c6fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8d1c7000 -     0x7fff8d1ceffb  libcopyfile.dylib (103.92.1) <CF29DFF6-0589-3590-834C-82E2316612E8> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8db04000 -     0x7fff8dbf5ff9  libiconv.2.dylib (41) <BB44B115-AC32-3877-A0ED-AEC6232A4563> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff8e3bf000 -     0x7fff8e3e6ffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff8f358000 -     0x7fff8f360fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.92.1) <17B03FFD-92C5-3282-9981-EBB28B456207> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff900c9000 -     0x7fff900cafff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11.1) <0D0B13EA-6B7A-3AC8-BE60-B548543BEB77> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff900cb000 -     0x7fff900f2ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff9057f000 -     0x7fff90586ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff908f2000 -     0x7fff908f9ff8  liblaunch.dylib (842.92.1) <A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff908fa000 -     0x7fff90903ffb  libsystem_notify.dylib (121.20.1) <9B34B4FE-F5AD-3F09-A5F0-46AFF3571323> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff91d1c000 -     0x7fff91d1eff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff91d36000 -     0x7fff91d84fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff922bc000 -     0x7fff922c0ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff922c1000 -     0x7fff922c8fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff92de2000 -     0x7fff92df3ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff939cc000 -     0x7fff939fbfd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff93c9e000 -     0x7fff93ca3ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff94330000 -     0x7fff94341ff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff94342000 -     0x7fff9435eff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.115.4) <9EDE872E-2A9E-3A78-8E1D-AB790794A098> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff9448e000 -     0x7fff9448fff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <E303F2F8-A8CF-3DF3-84B3-F2D0EE41CCF6> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff9496c000 -     0x7fff94987ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff94ed6000 -     0x7fff94edbfff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff9528d000 -     0x7fff95472fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.17) <729BD6DA-1F63-3E72-A148-26F21EBF52BB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff9555e000 -     0x7fff9555fffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff955ee000 -     0x7fff955f2ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.90.3) <4E51D5B0-92A0-3D0D-B90E-495A1ED3E391> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff95781000 -     0x7fff9592ef27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff95931000 -     0x7fff959baff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.90.3) <6FD3A400-4BB2-3B95-B90C-BE6E9D0D78FA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff95cfe000 -     0x7fff95d50fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 630
    thread_create: 1
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=78.9M resident=54.4M(69%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=24.5M(31%)
Writable regions: Total=17.7M written=336K(2%) resident=404K(2%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=17.3M(98%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             9396K
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                             1352K
__LINKEDIT                         67.3M
__TEXT                             11.6M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             154.0M
```

Comment: Does `brew reinstall rlog` help? What's your `brew config` look like / what hardware is this running on?

Comment: Reinstalling `rlog` did fix the issue actually. This is a rather old 2008 aluminium iMac and the config looks like above (just added).